# How is it that a dial-up modem can achieve 33.6Kbit/s with only 3100Hz of bandwidth?

Tags: modulation, bandwidth, spectral-efficiency

My understanding is that plain old telephone service passes frequencies between 300Hz and 3400Hz. How is it that a V.34 modem in the late 90s would be able to achieve data rates of 33,600bits/s with this amount of signal bandwidth? That's nearly 11 bits/hz which is a significantly higher spectral efficiency than many modern technologies (e.g. DOCSIS 3.1, 802.11AC, 4G LTE, etc).

Comment: Wow!  Thems were the olden daze.  i forgot.  Didn't they get to be 56K modems?  Before DSL?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson My understanding is that 56K speeds weren't achieved with the same end-to-end analog. I know that in the late 90s I had a V.92 modem but never got anything over 33.6K from my ISP.

Comment: It's all just a function bandwidth times SNR. DOCSIS 3.1 supports 4096 QAM which is 12 bits/symbol or 24 bits per Hz (theoretically)

Comment: @Hilmar My math could be wrong but I think that for a channel capacity of 33.6Kbit/s with a bandwidth of 3.1KHz would require a SNR of 66dB assuming your modulation was right at the Shannon-Hartley limit. That seems suspect.

Comment: How you get to the 66db?

Comment: @Moti Correction, 65dB. 3100 * log2(1+(10^(x/20))) = 33600

Comment: @Chris_F $2^{33600/3100}-1\approx 1830$, which is less than 33 dB.

Comment: yeah, you're using the "wrong" dB. it's $10^{x/10}$, not $/20$; SNR is a **power**, not an **amplitude** ratio.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm having a hard time finding any information on what kind of SNR you would expect from crummy old American phone lines that in the 90s were probably already 40 years old. 33dB still sounds like it could be hard to believe.

Comment: nah, that sounds pretty reasonable. Note that 33600 bit/s is also the maximum rate, so that's the SNR after which better SNRs do no longer allow for higher transmission speeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](https://www.jkaudio.com/article_10.htm) quotes the SNR of a phone line at 45 dB.

Combine this with a one sided bandwidth of about 3 kHz and you get a maximum channel capacity of about 45 kb/s.

45dB SNR  is a perfectly reasonable assumption for a phone line, it's not great but certainly workable for speech. It corresponds roughly to the noise floor of a 7 bit A/D converter, so it's really not that outlandish.

Answer (score 1):

Phone lines presumably have higher SNR than your typical power/interference limited radio link. Plus, wired links tends to have less reflections and be more stable, thus the fundamental limits bandwidth and SNR in a Shannon sense was probably easier to achieve than todays variable and reflective radio channels (requiring modern tech).